# Exchange server 2013 with Javamail IMAP: Implement the categorize function

Tags: jakarta-mail, exchange-server, imap

#### Background

I start to work with **Microsoft Exchange Server 2013** & **Javamail 1.5.6**
I am making a Java client and currently I am able to connect to mailbox by IMAP protocol and LIST/SEARCH emails.

#### My question

I want to implement a function that use Java code to **categorize** mails, the result should be the same as below function in outlook↓

(1) Right click on a mail, click **Categorize**, then select a target label

[image]

(2) The label is on the mail now:

[image]

#### My own research

1. I go through Javamail API but find nothing about this.
2. Then, I have a quick look at [IMAP: RFC 3501: INTERNET MESSAGE ACCESS PROTOCOL - VERSION 4rev1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501), but not able to find anything about **Categorize**, seems it is not standard IMAP capabilities?
3. Then I found this post: [Getting Gmail labels using javamail](http://www.yoxel.com/blog/latest-by-date-and-by-id/), the guy did his own extension by using `((IMAPFolder) folder).doCommand()`:

```
    final MessageSet[] mSets = MessageSet.createMessageSets(mns);
    ((IMAPFolder) folder).doCommand(new IMAPFolder.ProtocolCommand() {

    @Override
    public Object doCommand(IMAPProtocol p) throws ProtocolException {
        try {
            Response[] r = p.fetch(mSets, "X-GM-LABELS X-GM-THRID");
            for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                if (!FetchResponse.class.isInstance(r[i]))
                    continue;

                // Got a FetchResponse.
                GmailFetchResponse gfr = new GmailFetchResponse(
                                ((FetchResponse) r[i]).toString());
                // Use gfr.getNumber() to get the msg number
                for (int j = 0; j < gfr.getItemCount(); j++) {
                    Item item = gfr.getItem(j);
                    if (X_GM_LABELS.class.isInstance(item))
                        // get the labels
                        ((X_GM_LABELS) item).x_gm_labels);
                }
            }
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            logError(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }
    });
```

It looks like the guy construct his own commands by extend `IMAPProtocol` class.

But I couldn't find anything about commands of Microsoft Exchange server, can you help me on this?

Comment: It may not just be exposed.  You'd need to use EWS or the like.

Comment: Perhaps these are accessible as ["user flags"](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Flags.html#getUserFlags--) in IMAP?  If not, you'll probably have to use EWS.